# jQuery adding and removing classes on Anchor

Tags: jquery, css

I can't figure out why I cant remove a class from a  then add a new one.
I can change its css using .css(...) but using .removeClass and .addClass dont seem to work.

I am using add and remove class on some spans and that works just fine.
Anyone know what i am doing wrong? Thanks so much!

the html

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li><span>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="#">Home</a></span></li>
  <li><span>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="#">Test</a></span></li>
  <li><span>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="#">Test</a></span></li>
  <li><span>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="#">LaLa</a></span></li>
  <li><span>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="#">Test</a></span></li>
  <li><span>&nbsp;</span><span><a href="#">Blah</a></span></li>
 </ul>
```

the css

```
.menuText{

    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;

}

.menuTextA{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1A4588;
}
```

the jquery

```
$('li', 'ul#menu').each(function() {

                $(this).mouseover(function() {

                    $('span', this).eq(0).removeClass('menuTabLeft'); // works
                    $('span', this).eq(1).removeClass('menuTabRight'); // works

                    $('span', this).eq(0).addClass('menuTabLeftA'); // works
                    $('span', this).eq(1).addClass('menuTabRightA'); // works

                    //$('a', this).eq(0).removeClass('menuText'); // doesnt work 
                    //$('a', this).eq(0).addClass('menuTextA'); // doesnt work

                    $('a', this).eq(0).css('color', '#1A4588'); // works
    });
 });
```

Comment: If i copy and paste the code in a test page and uncomment the commented parts, and remove the //works line, it works as expected. So the problem is not with your code.

Comment: I would guess you have other CSS rules that override .menuText / .menuTextA

Comment: Isn't using .each(...) redundant? Can't you just apply the mouseover behavior definition directly to the resulting jQuery collection of your initial selector?  Not that this should make any difference, but it's just something that could be cleaned up and possibly eliminate the problem.

Comment: @Peter good call, i just changed that. Thanks for the tip. @Greg thats exactly what the problem was!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this for a quick fix:

```
$("#menu li").each(function() {
    $(this).mouseover(function() {
        var elems = $("span", this);
        $(elems[0]).removeClass("menuTabLeft").addClass("menuTabLeftA");
        $(elems[1]).removeClass("menuTabRight").addClass("menuTabRightA");
        $('a', this).removeClass("menuText").addClass("menuTextA");
    });
});
```

But for a better fix (no script needed):

```
#menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
     font-size: 30px;
}

#menu a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1A4588;
     font-size: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you just use the CSS psuedo-selector?

```
.menuText:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #1A4588;
}
```